# test data separation

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

Are there frameworks that facilitates separation test data from test code?

I have found [one](http://jtestcase.sourceforge.net), but it seems to be inactive (last activity was several years ago). I just wonder if there are any more recent frameworks?

Comment: Why does this need a framework?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to accomplish, what problem you are trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @francis-upton, I need to separate test data from test code. For example I have 100 possible variants of input values that has to be supplied to method. How can I organize them? Hardcode? Invent own format to store? That is why I need a library.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG is a comprehensive testing framework for Java. It support [DataProviders](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders)

Write your own provider that takes data from file or anywhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately we use junit as main testing framework, so that is not applicable.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question because you are asking about framework. JUnit has something like that. It's called Parametrized runner (not well documented): http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html